# Save screenshot with document name and page

Tags: macbook-pro, screen-capture

Is it possible to add the document name and document page when I do screenshots?

So, if I open a PDF and do a screenshot at page 6, I will have: 
Document Name | Page 6 | Screen Shot 2012-06-12 at 8.02.40 AM

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to add the document name and document page when I do screenshots?

Using just what's setup by default, no; however, aside from doing it manually, it can be automated to various degrees depending on what methods and applications are involved.

> So, if I open a PDF and do a screenshot at page 6, I will have: Document Name | Page 6 | Screen Shot 2012-06-12 at 8.02.40 AM

As an example, using **Preview** and **AppleScript** along with an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*, and assigning it a *keyboard shortcut* in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**, the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown further below, will take a *screen shot* of either the *full window* of the *front window* of **Preview** or just its document *scroll area*, depending on its *settings*.

The *name* of the *screen shot* will be in the *format* shown quoted above from your question.

---

Here is a sample *file name* and a scaled down image of the *screen shot* taken of the document *scroll area* in **Preview** of **The Room Where It Happened** and was saved as:

**The Room Where It Happened | 3 | Snap Shot 2020-7-7 at 8.55.30 PM.png**

[image: Screen Shot]

---

There are three *variables* at the start of the *example* **AppleScript** *code* that are *user* configurable:

- `saveToLocation` - Where the *screen shot* will be saved.

  - The default is the users **Pictures** *folder*.
- `ssFileType` - Which can be set to: **png**, **jpg**, **pdf** or **tiff**.

  - The default is: **png**
- `captureArea` - Which gets set to to either **whole window**, or **scroll area**.

  - The default is: **scroll area** (of the document, not whatever shows in the **Sidebar**.)

You should not need to edit the *code* below these initial *variables*, unless necessary, and the *code* is lightly commented to help one understand what it is doing.

---

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* was tested as an **Automator** *Service* in **macOS High Sierra**, and should also work as a *Quick Action* in **macOS Mojave** and later. The **Automator** *Service* was assigned a *keyboard shortcut* of **⌥⌘S** and was pressed while **Preview** had focus and was frontmost.

```
--  # Set the save to location, screen shot file type, and the capture area.
--  # The code below these three settings should not need to be edited.

--  # The saveToLocation must be in the form of a 
--  # POSIX path for the screencapture command.

set saveToLocation to POSIX path of (path to pictures folder)

--  # ssFileType can be set to "png", "jpg", "pdf" or "tiff".

set ssFileType to "png"

--  # Set the capture area to either 'whole window', or just the 'scroll area'.

set captureArea to "scroll area"


--  # Do not edit the code below this line unless necessary.


--  # In Preview, when a PDF document is opened, the 'window name' is in the
--  # format of 'filename (page x of y)' for multi-page documents, or  
--  # 'filename (1 page)' for single-page documents, and the 'filename' may contain '.pdf'.
--  # Example: "The Room Where It Happened.pdf (page 1 of 570)"
--  # Parse the text items of the 'window name' for parts of the screen shot name.


--  # Get then name of the first window of Preview.

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    set windowName to ¬
        the name of ¬
            the front window of ¬
                application process "Preview"

--  # Check to see the document is a PDF, and terminate if not.

if windowName contains "(page" or windowName contains "page)" then
    -- # Document is a PDF file. Continue processing...
else
    return
end if

--  # Parse 'windowName' to get the doc name and page number.

set text item delimiters to "("

set documentName to ¬
    the first text item of ¬
        the windowName

if documentName contains ".pdf" then
    set documentName to ¬
        characters 1 thru -6 of ¬
        the first text item of ¬
            the windowName
else
    set documentName to ¬
        characters 1 thru -2 of ¬
        the first text item of ¬
            the windowName
end if

if the first word of ¬
    the second text item of ¬
        the windowName is "1" then
    set pageNumber to ¬
        the first word of ¬
            the second text item of ¬
                the windowName
else
    set pageNumber to ¬
        the second word of ¬
            the second text item of ¬
                the windowName
end if

set text item delimiters to ""

--  # Get position and size of the front window or the
--  # document scroll area of Preview for the screen shot.

if captureArea contains "whole window" then
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        set windowPositionSize to {position, size} of ¬
            the front window of ¬
                application process "Preview"
else if captureArea contains "scroll area" then
    tell application "System Events"
        if exists scroll area 2 of ¬
            splitter group 1 of ¬
            window 1 of ¬
            application process "Preview" then
            set windowPositionSize to ¬
                {position, size} of ¬
                scroll area 2 of ¬
                splitter group 1 of ¬
                window 1 of ¬
                application process "Preview"
        else
            set windowPositionSize to ¬
                {position, size} of ¬
                scroll area 1 of ¬
                splitter group 1 of ¬
                window 1 of ¬
                application process "Preview"
        end if
    end tell
end if

set x to item 1 of item 1 of windowPositionSize
set y to item 2 of item 1 of windowPositionSize
set w to item 1 of item 2 of windowPositionSize
set h to item 2 of item 2 of windowPositionSize

--  # Build out the date time string for the screen shot file name.

set currentDate to (current date)
set d to day of currentDate
set m to month of currentDate as integer
set yr to year of currentDate
set t to time string of currentDate

--  # Replace ':' with '.' in the 'time string'.

set text item delimiters to ":"
set t to text items of t
set text item delimiters to "."
set t to t as string
set text item delimiters to ""

--  # Set the screen shot file name.

set ssFileName to ¬
    (documentName as string) & ¬
    " | " & ¬
    pageNumber & ¬
    " | " & ¬
    "Snap Shot " & yr & "-" & d & "-" & m & " at " & t & "." & ssFileType

--  # Define the shell command.

set myShellCMD to ¬
    "screencapture -R" & x & "," & y & "," & w & "," & h & " -t " & ¬
    ssFileType & space & (saveToLocation & ssFileName)'s quoted form

--  # Take the screen shot.

do shell script myShellCMD
```

---

For the **Run Shell Script** *action* in the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*, replace the entire default *code* with the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, and then edit the first three *variables* as wanted, if the *default values* are not what you want.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

You will have to do that manually. You can open screenshot in Preview and do a "save As". Add your desired info before the screenshot name and then save the file with your new name.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I am but I'm not that far along!  and I'm dividing my time so Applescript has gotten pushed aside at times.